# file_get_contents doesn't get all content

Tags: php

I try to **get content list of CPU compatible with motherboard** but the function `file_get_contents()` returns the page content without CPU list

```
url='https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z390%20Phantom%20Gaming%206/index.pl.asp#CPU';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU data is not part of this page. When a user clicks the "CPU" link on the page javascript is executed to get and display this json file: https://www.asrock.com/mb/productGet.asp?cat=CPU&Model=Z390%20Phantom%20Gaming%206

What you need to do is get this file either server side (PHP) or Client side javascript convert it into a form suitable for display ("decode" the json).

Comment: Thanks! Address to json file we can see in Developer tools -> Network